# How can i upload file to dropbox with the same name as of the file

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox-api

I'm using `"benjamincrozat/laravel-dropbox-driver"` with Laravel `5.6.33`.

I can successfully upload files to the dropbox account but there is only one problem the file I upload is of different name then the one that is uploaded to dropbox can any one help?

I can successfully upload files to dropbox but there issue I'm having is the one I upload has a different name when I upload it. The file's original name is **new.txt** and ends up saving as **icPWavRotv4FzPo5EHMdFAtsb7whc8lipiGVPuFP.txt**.

I have searched on the internet and came across `getClientOriginalName()` method but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

**Code**

```
public function uploadToDropbox(Request $RequestInput)
{
   $file_src=$RequestInput->file('upload_file')->getClientOriginalName();

   $is_file_uploaded=Storage::disk('dropbox')->put('public-uploads',$file_src);

   if($is_file_uploaded) {
       return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg'=>'Succesfuly file uploaded to dropbox']);
   } else {
       return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg'=>'file failed to upload on dropbox']);
   }
}
```

**Expected Results**

When I upload a file called **new.txt** I expect it to save as **new.txt**.

Comment: I know nothing about the laravel, so my question here for laravel users: what the sense to use https://github.com/benjamincrozat/laravel-dropbox-driver/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php when the only one source file of this "dropbox driver" contains 4 lines of real code?

Comment: @user1597430 It seems to just be a wrapper around other people's code that perform this functionality, kinda pointless but when has that ever stopped programmers.

Comment: yeah i'm currently learning laravel so i followed a tutorial on youtube. Do you know of anything that  can solve this issue that i'm currently having?